# Visual "strings" Tool for Windows

Tags: windows

I'm looking for something that does what the unix "strings" program does, but in Windows. And visual, too.

Occasionally, I have a binary file and want to see if certain strings are present in it. Right now, I use notepad, and turn on wordwrap, and just ignore all the garbage and visually search for strings.

Anyone have anything neat they use? (Preferably free or cheap.)

Comment: 'Extract Text' by Juan M. Aguirregabiria, available from http://tp.lc.ehu.es/jma/win95.html, will do this.

Answer (score 4):

not sure about the visual part but there you go:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

Comment: there is also "Process Explorer" where we can see the strings of a process.

Comment: he's talking about files dude.